# how to access the Objects initialized inside constructor(JAVA)?

Tags: java, object, constructor

I have demonstrated an example below for my questions.

```
class B {
    int name;

    public int getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(int name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
}

class A {

    public A() {
        // initializing object B 
        B b = new B();
    }
}

class MainClass {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        A a = new A();
    }
}
```

How I access the object of B in the Mainclass which is initialized inside the class A Constructor?

Comment: Nikak. In order to do this make  b property of class A, and provide getter for it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way to achieve this would be to add a getter method inside your `A` class which exposes the instance of `B`:

```
public class A {
    private B b;

    public A() {
        b = new B();
    }

    public B getB() {
        return b;
    }
}
```

**Usage:**

```
A a = new A();
B myB = a.getB();
```

Comment: @JunedAhsan Many thanks and blessings for your feedback and mercies.

Answer (score 0):

How about

```
class A {
  private B b;

  public A() {
    // initializing object B 
    b = new B();
  }

  public B getB () {
   return b;
  }
}
```

from mainClass

```
A a = new A();
B b = a.getB ();
```